# Elasticsearch script sort based on element exists in array

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got such a list of documents:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Ram",
    "status": 1,
    "activity": "Poster Design",
    "categories": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  },
  {
    "id": 124,
    "name": "Leo",
    "categories": [5],
    "status": 1,
    "activity": "Brochure"
  },
  {
    "id": 126,
    "name": "Leo",
    "categories": [3],
    "status": 1,
    "activity": "Brochure"
  },
  {
    "id": 134,
    "name": "Levin",
    "categories": [1],
    "status": 1,
    "activity": "3D Printing"
  }
]
```

And I want the output like if I sort categories contains 1 (this can be 3 or 5 or 7). So it will sort all records with categories contains 1 first after all others.

So if the sorting is done by 3 output should be

```json
    [
      {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Ram",
        "status": 1,
        "activity": "Poster Design",
        "categories": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
      },
      {
        "id": 126,
        "name": "Leo",
        "categories": [3],
        "status": 1,
        "activity": "Brochure"
      },
      {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "Leo",
        "categories": [5],
        "status": 1,
        "activity": "Brochure"
      },
      {
        "id": 134,
        "name": "Levin",
        "categories": [1],
        "status": 1,
        "activity": "3D Printing"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

When sorting by array fields, you need to specify a sort mode.

```json
POST /_search
{
  "sort": [{ "categories": { "order": "asc", "mode": "min" } }]
}
```

In your case - it'll sort documents that contain `1` in categories at the beginning.

Read more in docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_sort_mode_option

**Update**

You could avoid sorting at all and use a query to boost values with specific `category_id`:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "categories": {
              "value": 3,
              "boost": 2.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`must` part will match all documents and the `should` clause will add an additional boost to documents that have `3` in its `categories`, effectively ranking them higher.

Comment: But what if I need to sort by 3, this number is dynamic which I will get from the search.

Comment: @sagar43 updated with alternative approach.

Comment: Added in the question